# Extracting number of rows using df.query() inside for-loops?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on a data frame that has several `branch_id`s for each state and I would like to extract the number of rows for each of the id in each of the state. For this I'm using a for loop like so:

```py
for branch in prim_data.loc[prim_data.state == 'AZ'].branch_id.unique():
    print("{0} :: {1} samples".format(branch, len(prim_data.query("branch_id == branch and state == 'AZ'"))))
```

But executing this code is giving me an error and a long traceback:

```py
UndefinedVariableError: name 'branch' is not defined
```

Is there a better way to achieve this? For info regarding the data frame, it looks like this:

```py
segment    branch_id    state
1          1            AZ
1          3            AZ
2          7            AZ
```

There are a number of states but let's focus on just one state for the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UndefinedVariableError: name 'branch' is not defined`

query() somehow do not accept variable in a string expression? Instead, you can use F-string to do it.

```
for branch in prim_data.loc[prim_data.state == 'AZ'].branch_id.unique():
    print(len(prim_data.query(f"(branch_id == {branch}) & (state == 'AZ')")))
```

Is there a better way to achieve this?
Yes, you can use group_by to do it.

```
prim_data.groupby(['state','branch_id']).count()
```